# Communication between pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, widget, return

My goal is to create a quiz application on flutter that contains different types of questions and answers. For example, we write the answer using textfield on one page and I use answer options on another page. For this, I wrote 5 widgets without using scaffold. Actually, it's all a screen.  I need to rotate the widgets with the necessary orientation based on the answers given by the user on the homepage. If the answer is correct, another widget will be called. But a I don't know how to create this cycle. By the way, I'm a  new flutter user :)

This is the main page where I want to direct the widgets

```
class LearnView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LearnView({super.key, required this.levelNumber});
  final int levelNumber;

  @override
  State<LearnView> createState() => _LearnViewState();
}

class _LearnViewState extends State<LearnView> {
  int itemIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(AppKeys.kAppName),
      ),
      body: Consumer<LearnDatas>(
        builder: (context, learnDatas, child) {
          learnDatas.setLevel(widget.levelNumber);
          List<BrailleModel> items = learnDatas.mergeItems();
          Widget child = LearnImageTestView(model: items[itemIndex]);
          //LearnShowModelView(model: items[itemIndex]);
          return Column(
            children: [
              const LearnProgressWidget(),
              Expanded(child: child),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is one of the option pages I mentioned. don't be fooled by the crowd, these are trials :)

```
class LearnImageTestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LearnImageTestView({super.key, required this.model});
  final BrailleModel model;

  @override
  State<LearnImageTestView> createState() => _LearnImageTestViewState();
}

class _LearnImageTestViewState extends State<LearnImageTestView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: AppPaddings.kSymmetricPadding2x,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: LearnQuestionContainer(
                child: Text(
              widget.model.name,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
            )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: AppPaddings.kVerticalPadding2x,
              child: GridView(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                        ),
                        child: BrailleImageWidget(brailleModel: widget.model),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/alphabet/img_b_harfi.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/alphabet/img_c_harfi.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/alphabet/img_a_harfi.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My goal here is to return true to the main page and redirect to the other exam page if the correct button is pressed on the page where these options are available. I thought that if I made them all pages, it wouldn't make sense to constantly switch between pages, I'm open to suggestions if my idea is wrong. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You can use callback method to pass event on parent widget.

Comment: Better use a state management solution like, Proviver, Bloc, or Riverpod to access any data anywhere in the app.

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/pkmk72h i want the app to work this way. As I said, I'm new to flutter, which one do you recommend

Comment: Ignore provider, as riverpod has taken over for it.